# Not able to access Centos Apache page from another Computer

Tags: centos, apache, iptables

Today a started apache on CentOS and I'm able to open the test page on same machine as localhost. But I'm unable to open it using another computer. The CentOS server is on a VLAN (using switch) behind a router. I'm able to ping the server from other side using my laptop. But I'm not able to open the test page in my browser. I have another server in same VLAN which I'm able to access from my laptop.

Also here is some entries of iptables -L

```
Chain INPUT 
ACCEPT  tcp   --  anywhere    anywhere   tcp:dtp:http
ACCEPT  udp   --  anywhere    anywhere   udp:dtp:http
REJECT  all   --  anywhere    anywhere   reject-with  icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD
REJECT  all   --  anywhere    anywhere   reject-with  icmp-host-prohibited
```

I'm not sure what else I need to check.

Answer (score 0):

Security theory tells to first drop the firewall and test (`iptables -F`). If you can access then it is really a iptables issue, if you are still unable to reach your service, try looking if you got any specific bind: `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "`  if you see something like:

`"tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     "`

means that your server is only listening on localhost ip, you should check on specific httpd binds on `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`

If you require some more help, keep posting =)